# Create an image input to save to DB and storage folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have a Laravel blog application and wish to add images under my posts. I have read the Laravel Storage documentation, looked at several tutorials and discussions, but I'm still very confused. I am trying to save a image to a storage folder and the path to the DB to retrieve later. I have linked my storage file using `php artisan storage:link`. The error I get is `Call to a member function store() on null`

Here is my HTML and ajax call:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Create your post</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="post">Post</label>
      <textarea name="post" rows="8" cols="80" id="post" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="image">Add image</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Post" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var post = $("#post").val();
    var image = $("#image").val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url:'/post/create/create',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        title: title,
        post: post,
        image: image,
      },

      success:function(response){
        toastr.success(response.response);
      },
      error: function(error){
        toastr.error(error.error)
      }
    });

  });
});


</script>
@endsection
```

Here is my Posts Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
use App\Comment;
use Auth;

class PostController extends Controller{
    public function create(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'post' => 'required',

      ]);

      $path = $request->file('image')->store('images');

      $post = new Post;
      $post->title = $request->input('title');
      $post->post = $request->input('post');
      $post->uploadImage = $path;
      $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

      $post->save();

      $response = [
        'response' => 'Post Created Successfully',
        'error' => 'Something went wrong'
      ];

      return response()->json($response);
    }

}
```

Comment: your problem is not about the storage. your controller code is absolutely fine. the problem is that you are sending the image in ajax wrong, so there is not file to save

Comment: Thank you - how would I send it in the ajax?

Comment: why don't you try packages like plupload : https://github.com/jildertmiedema/laravel-plupload

Answer (score 0):

To upload an image using `ajax` you have to use `FormData` like:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var fileData = $('#image').prop('files')[0];
var name     = $('#name').val();
formData.append('fileData', fileData);
formData.append('name', name);
```

and use it in ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    method: 'post',
    data: formData,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(response){
        // yoou code here
    }
});
```

On the server side you can get the `formData` and all the appended values are available on their respective indexes.

Comment: I don't understand all your code - why are you declaring a name variable? What is it's role?

Comment: The normal `ajax` with `key` : `value` will not work for file upload, `formData` is used for it, we can create an object of it and append all the element in  it, just like creating a hidden form and append all the values into it and then submit the form.

Comment: Yes, but in your code you have a name variable. I am asking about that.

Comment: That's just an example, you can append as many values as you want, its just like `formData.append('key', value);`